# How to create link in textview to open image

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I need to create a TextView and link it to an image from sdcard. So when user taps on it, it will open up the image. I used the following code, but it does not work:

```
TextView tv = new TextView();
tv.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
tv.setAutoLinkMask(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"file:///sdcard/PIC_20150721_- 1_1245263.jpg\">PIC_20150721_-1_1245263.jpg</a>"));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

The problems I have so far: 
On screen, it does show PIC_20150721_1245263.jpg, but it display the text like this: PIC_20150721_-1_**1245263.jpg**, and only **1245263.jpg** is clickable. It does not show the whole file name as clickable. And when I click it, it opens us chrome with URL as: **1245263.jpg** and then says not able to find such page.

How to make it support file://xxxx format?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use an ImageView for this purpose?

Comment: why don't you just perform click event of textView and open gallery intent inside with your image path. may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25168186/5148289) will help you.

Comment: why not use `ClickableSpan` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) and use Linkify class like this:

```
TextView tv = new TextView();
tv.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
tv.setAutoLinkMask(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"file:///sdcard/PIC_20150721_- 1_1245263.jpg\">PIC_20150721_-1_1245263.jpg</a>"));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.ALL);
```